# Hotkey with LowLevel Keyboard Hook

Tags: c++, keyboard, hook

my program knows 2 states: A annd B, where A is the default state.
When you press ALT-# it should change it's state to B and when you release the combination it should go back to A.
This should work with a LowLevel Keyboard hook but it seems I am stuck somewhere.

```
#define VK_POUND 0xBF // 191 - the # key
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { 
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) { 
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbdStruct = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam); 

        switch (wParam) { 
            case WM_KEYDOWN: {
                std::cout << kbdStruct->vkCode << "\n";
                if (kbdStruct->vkCode == VK_POUND && kbdStruct->flags & LLKHF_ALTDOWN) { 
                    MessageBox(NULL, "WE GOT IT", "", MB_OK); 
                } 
            } break; 

            case WM_KEYUP: { 
            } break; 
        } 
    } 

    return CallNextHookEx(g_HotKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

What confuses me: When I press the combination ALT and # there is no output in the console.

Comment: A low-level keyboard hook requires a message loop to be functional.  Consoles mode programs don't normally pump a message loop.

Comment: Why do you think I am using consoles mode? I am using a legit Win32 application

Comment: Quote: `there is no output in the console.`

Comment: Second mysterious part of this question is how you have a keyboard with a dedicated # key.  Most keyboard layouts require pressing the Shift key, like Shift+3 on a US keyboard layout.  Virtual keys are not the same thing as typing keys, the # character isn't normally produced until the keyboard message is translated.  Which doesn't happen, and cannot work, in a low-level keyboard hook.

Comment: Lol I am using the console output for debugging reasons. I am using a keyboard with the german(?) layout so I do have a seperate # key.

To simplify it: Lets say I want to detect the ALT-A combination.

Comment: Sigh, this is going to be a lot of work.  To avoid pulling more teeth, set a debugger breakpoint in the callback.  Run your program and press a key.  If it doesn't break then the code you posted doesn't have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: I solved it myself: I have to use **WM_SYSKEYDOWN** and **NOT WM_KEYDOWN**. Thank you for the time you spent on my request!